# Optimization flag is not taken into account when compiling with arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c, makefile, arm, compiler-optimization, libopencm3

I want to compile a program with `arm-none-eabi-gcc 9.2.1` using the [libopencm3](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3) project and run it on ARM Cortex-M4 processors. My program is composed of two files: `main.c`

```
#include "../common/stm32wrapper.h"
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned int  u32;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

int main(void)
{
    clock_setup();
    gpio_setup();
    usart_setup(115200);
    flash_setup();

    SCS_DEMCR |= SCS_DEMCR_TRCENA;
    DWT_CYCCNT = 0;
    DWT_CTRL |= DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA;

    u32 oldcount, newcount;
    u32 a = 0x75;
    u32 b = 0x14;
    char buffer[36];
    oldcount = DWT_CYCCNT;
    u32 c = test(a,b);
    newcount = DWT_CYCCNT-oldcount;
    sprintf(buffer, "cycles: %d, %08x", newcount, c);
    send_USART_str(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

and `test.c`.

```
uint32_t test(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    uint32_t tmp0, tmp1;
    uint32_t c;

    for(int i = 0; i< 4096; i++) {
        tmp0 = a & 0xff;
        tmp1 = b & 0xff;
        c = tmp0 ^ tmp1 ^ (a>>(i/512)) ^ (b >> (i/1024));
    }
    return c;
}
```

To compile my program, I use the following makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean

PREFIX  ?= arm-none-eabi
CC      = $(PREFIX)-gcc -v
LD      = $(PREFIX)-gcc -v
OBJCOPY = $(PREFIX)-objcopy
OBJDUMP = $(PREFIX)-objdump
GDB     = $(PREFIX)-gdb

OPENCM3DIR = ../libopencm3
ARMNONEEABIDIR = /usr/arm-none-eabi
COMMONDIR = ../common

all: test_m4.bin

test_m4.%: ARCH_FLAGS = -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
test_m4.o: CFLAGS += -DSTM32F4
$(COMMONDIR)/stm32f4_wrapper.o: CFLAGS += -DSTM32F4
test_m4.elf: LDSCRIPT = $(COMMONDIR)/stm32f4-discovery.ld
test_m4.elf: LDFLAGS += -L$(OPENCM3DIR)/lib/ -lopencm3_stm32f4
test_m4.elf: OBJS += $(COMMONDIR)/stm32f4_wrapper.o 
test_m4.elf: $(COMMONDIR)/stm32f4_wrapper.o $(OPENCM3DIR)/lib/libopencm3_stm32f4.a

CFLAGS      += -O3 \
           -Wall -Wextra -Wimplicit-function-declaration \
           -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
           -Wundef -Wshadow \
           -I$(ARMNONEEABIDIR)/include -I$(OPENCM3DIR)/include \
           -fno-common $(ARCH_FLAGS) -MD \
           -ftime-report
LDFLAGS     += --static -Wl,--start-group -lc -lgcc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group \
           -T$(LDSCRIPT) -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections,--no-print-gc-sections \
           $(ARCH_FLAGS)

OBJS        += test.c

%.bin: %.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -Obinary $^ $@

%.elf: %.o $(OBJS) $(LDSCRIPT)
    $(LD) -o $@ $< $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

test%.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $^

%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.d *.elf *.bin
```

I can compile and run my code using this makefile. By running `make` I get the following output:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -v -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Wshadow -I/usr/arm-none-eabi/include -I../libopencm3/include -fno-common -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -MD -ftime-report -DSTM32F4 -o test_m4.o -c main.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
Target: arm-none-eabi
Configured with: /mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/src/gcc/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native --libexecdir=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/lib --infodir=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info --mandir=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/man --htmldir=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/html --pdfdir=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/pdf --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-plugins --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-newlib --with-headers=yes --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-sysroot=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/arm-none-eabi --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-gmp=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-mpfr=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-mpc=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-isl=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-libelf=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major' --with-multilib-list=rmprofile
Thread model: single
gcc version 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599] (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-O3' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wimplicit-function-declaration' '-Wredundant-decls' '-Wmissing-prototypes' '-Wstrict-prototypes' '-Wundef' '-Wshadow' '-I' '/usr/arm-none-eabi/include' '-I' '../libopencm3/include' '-fno-common' '-mthumb' '-mcpu=cortex-m4' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16' '-MD' '-ftime-report' '-D' 'STM32F4' '-o' 'test_m4.o' '-c' '-march=armv7e-m+fp'
 /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/cc1 -quiet -v -I /usr/arm-none-eabi/include -I ../libopencm3/include -imultilib thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard -iprefix /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/ -isysroot /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi -MD test_m4.d -MQ test_m4.o -D__USES_INITFINI__ -D STM32F4 main.c -quiet -dumpbase main.c -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -march=armv7e-m+fp -auxbase-strip test_m4.o -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Wshadow -version -fno-common -ftime-report -o /tmp/ccm5h1i9.s
GNU C17 (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) version 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599] (arm-none-eabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.4, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi/usr/local/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi/usr/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/arm-none-eabi/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 ../libopencm3/include
 /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include
 /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include-fixed
 /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include
End of search list.
GNU C17 (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) version 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599] (arm-none-eabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.4, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 4381e146d4f016ae8e44a645dba65184

Time variable                                   usr           sys          wall               GGC
 phase setup                        :   0.01 (  8%)   0.01 ( 20%)   0.03 ( 17%)    3569 kB ( 62%)
 phase parsing                      :   0.10 ( 83%)   0.04 ( 80%)   0.14 ( 78%)    2069 kB ( 36%)
 phase opt and generate             :   0.01 (  8%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  6%)     120 kB (  2%)
 preprocessing                      :   0.03 ( 25%)   0.03 ( 60%)   0.03 ( 17%)     889 kB ( 15%)
 lexical analysis                   :   0.04 ( 33%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.05 ( 28%)       0 kB (  0%)
 parser (global)                    :   0.02 ( 17%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 ( 22%)    1063 kB ( 18%)
 parser struct body                 :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  6%)      41 kB (  1%)
 parser enumerator list             :   0.01 (  8%)   0.01 ( 20%)   0.01 (  6%)      54 kB (  1%)
 tree gimplify                      :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  6%)       8 kB (  0%)
 initialize rtl                     :   0.01 (  8%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)       7 kB (  0%)
 TOTAL                              :   0.12          0.05          0.18           5767 kB
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-O3' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wimplicit-function-declaration' '-Wredundant-decls' '-Wmissing-prototypes' '-Wstrict-prototypes' '-Wundef' '-Wshadow' '-I' '/usr/arm-none-eabi/include' '-I' '../libopencm3/include' '-fno-common' '-mthumb' '-mcpu=cortex-m4' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16' '-MD' '-ftime-report' '-D' 'STM32F4' '-o' 'test_m4.o' '-c' '-march=armv7e-m+fp'
 /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/as -v -I /usr/arm-none-eabi/include -I ../libopencm3/include -march=armv7e-m -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -meabi=5 -o test_m4.o /tmp/ccm5h1i9.s
GNU assembler version 2.33.1 (arm-none-eabi) using BFD version (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) 2.33.1.20191025
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-O3' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wimplicit-function-declaration' '-Wredundant-decls' '-Wmissing-prototypes' '-Wstrict-prototypes' '-Wundef' '-Wshadow' '-I' '/usr/arm-none-eabi/include' '-I' '../libopencm3/include' '-fno-common' '-mthumb' '-mcpu=cortex-m4' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16' '-MD' '-ftime-report' '-D' 'STM32F4' '-o' 'test_m4.o' '-c' '-march=armv7e-m+fp'
arm-none-eabi-gcc -v -o test_m4.elf test_m4.o test.c ../common/stm32f4_wrapper.o  --static -Wl,--start-group -lc -lgcc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group -T../common/stm32f4-discovery.ld -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections,--no-print-gc-sections -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -L../libopencm3/lib/ -lopencm3_stm32f4
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-none-eabi
Configured with: /mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/src/gcc/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native --libexecdir=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/lib --infodir=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info --mandir=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/man --htmldir=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/html --pdfdir=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/pdf --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-plugins --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-newlib --with-headers=yes --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-sysroot=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/install-native/arm-none-eabi --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-gmp=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-mpfr=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-mpc=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-isl=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-libelf=/mnt/workspace/workspace/GCC-9-pipeline/jenkins-GCC-9-pipeline-100_20191030_1572397542/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major' --with-multilib-list=rmprofile
Thread model: single
gcc version 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599] (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test_m4.elf' '-static' '-T' '../common/stm32f4-discovery.ld' '-nostartfiles' '-mthumb' '-mcpu=cortex-m4' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16' '-L../libopencm3/lib/' '-march=armv7e-m+fp'
 /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/cc1 -quiet -v -imultilib thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard -iprefix /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/ -isysroot /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi -D__USES_INITFINI__ test.c -quiet -dumpbase test.c -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -march=armv7e-m+fp -auxbase test -version -o /tmp/cc3yny6o.s
GNU C17 (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) version 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599] (arm-none-eabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.4, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi/usr/local/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include
 /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include-fixed
 /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include
End of search list.
GNU C17 (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) version 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599] (arm-none-eabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.4, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version isl-0.18-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 4381e146d4f016ae8e44a645dba65184
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test_m4.elf' '-static' '-T' '../common/stm32f4-discovery.ld' '-nostartfiles' '-mthumb' '-mcpu=cortex-m4' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16' '-L../libopencm3/lib/' '-march=armv7e-m+fp'
 /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/as -v -march=armv7e-m -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -meabi=5 -o /tmp/ccfflDpW.o /tmp/cc3yny6o.s
GNU assembler version 2.33.1 (arm-none-eabi) using BFD version (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) 2.33.1.20191025
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/:/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test_m4.elf' '-static' '-T' '../common/stm32f4-discovery.ld' '-nostartfiles' '-mthumb' '-mcpu=cortex-m4' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16' '-L../libopencm3/lib/' '-march=armv7e-m+fp'
 /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/collect2 -plugin /usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc4qN1Kt.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc --sysroot=/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi -Bstatic -X -o test_m4.elf -L../libopencm3/lib/ -L/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard -L/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard -L/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard -L/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1 -L/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc -L/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib -L/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib test_m4.o /tmp/ccfflDpW.o ../common/stm32f4_wrapper.o --start-group -lc -lgcc -lnosys --end-group --gc-sections --no-print-gc-sections -lopencm3_stm32f4 --start-group -lgcc -lc --end-group -T ../common/stm32f4-discovery.ld
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test_m4.elf' '-static' '-T' '../common/stm32f4-discovery.ld' '-nostartfiles' '-mthumb' '-mcpu=cortex-m4' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16' '-L../libopencm3/lib/' '-march=armv7e-m+fp'
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Obinary test_m4.elf test_m4.bin
```

The thing that it seems the optimization flag does not seem to be taken into account, as no matter what I put, the generated binary is always the same and the program always print `cycles: 196645, 00000063`. By disassembling the binary I get the following output for both -Os and -O3 optimizations:

```
080001ac <main>:
 80001ac:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
 80001ae:   b08a        sub sp, #40 ; 0x28
 80001b0:   f006 fc06   bl  80069c0 <clock_setup>
 80001b4:   f006 fc1c   bl  80069f0 <gpio_setup>
 80001b8:   f44f 30e1   mov.w   r0, #115200 ; 0x1c200
 80001bc:   f006 fc32   bl  8006a24 <usart_setup>
 80001c0:   f006 fc52   bl  8006a68 <flash_setup>
 80001c4:   490e        ldr r1, [pc, #56]   ; (8000200 <main+0x54>)
 80001c6:   4c0f        ldr r4, [pc, #60]   ; (8000204 <main+0x58>)
 80001c8:   680b        ldr r3, [r1, #0]
 80001ca:   4a0f        ldr r2, [pc, #60]   ; (8000208 <main+0x5c>)
 80001cc:   2500        movs    r5, #0
 80001ce:   f043 7380   orr.w   r3, r3, #16777216   ; 0x1000000
 80001d2:   600b        str r3, [r1, #0]
 80001d4:   6025        str r5, [r4, #0]
 80001d6:   6813        ldr r3, [r2, #0]
 80001d8:   f043 0301   orr.w   r3, r3, #1
 80001dc:   6013        str r3, [r2, #0]
 80001de:   6826        ldr r6, [r4, #0]
 80001e0:   f000 f816   bl  8000210 <test>
 80001e4:   6822        ldr r2, [r4, #0]
 80001e6:   4909        ldr r1, [pc, #36]   ; (800020c <main+0x60>)
 80001e8:   4603        mov r3, r0
 80001ea:   1b92        subs    r2, r2, r6
 80001ec:   a801        add r0, sp, #4
 80001ee:   f006 fca5   bl  8006b3c <sprintf>
 80001f2:   a801        add r0, sp, #4
 80001f4:   f006 fc48   bl  8006a88 <send_USART_str>
 80001f8:   4628        mov r0, r5
 80001fa:   b00a        add sp, #40 ; 0x28
 80001fc:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
 80001fe:   bf00        nop
 8000200:   e000edfc    .word   0xe000edfc
 8000204:   e0001004    .word   0xe0001004
 8000208:   e0001000    .word   0xe0001000
 800020c:   0800c1e8    .word   0x0800c1e8

08000210 <test>:
 8000210:   b480        push    {r7}
 8000212:   b087        sub sp, #28
 8000214:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
 8000216:   2375        movs    r3, #117    ; 0x75
 8000218:   60fb        str r3, [r7, #12]
 800021a:   2314        movs    r3, #20
 800021c:   60bb        str r3, [r7, #8]
 800021e:   2300        movs    r3, #0
 8000220:   613b        str r3, [r7, #16]
 8000222:   e020        b.n 8000266 <test+0x56>
 8000224:   68fb        ldr r3, [r7, #12]
 8000226:   b2db        uxtb    r3, r3
 8000228:   607b        str r3, [r7, #4]
 800022a:   68bb        ldr r3, [r7, #8]
 800022c:   b2db        uxtb    r3, r3
 800022e:   603b        str r3, [r7, #0]
 8000230:   687a        ldr r2, [r7, #4]
 8000232:   683b        ldr r3, [r7, #0]
 8000234:   405a        eors    r2, r3
 8000236:   693b        ldr r3, [r7, #16]
 8000238:   2b00        cmp r3, #0
 800023a:   da01        bge.n   8000240 <test+0x30>
 800023c:   f203 13ff   addw    r3, r3, #511    ; 0x1ff
 8000240:   125b        asrs    r3, r3, #9
 8000242:   4619        mov r1, r3
 8000244:   68fb        ldr r3, [r7, #12]
 8000246:   40cb        lsrs    r3, r1
 8000248:   405a        eors    r2, r3
 800024a:   693b        ldr r3, [r7, #16]
 800024c:   2b00        cmp r3, #0
 800024e:   da01        bge.n   8000254 <test+0x44>
 8000250:   f203 33ff   addw    r3, r3, #1023   ; 0x3ff
 8000254:   129b        asrs    r3, r3, #10
 8000256:   4619        mov r1, r3
 8000258:   68bb        ldr r3, [r7, #8]
 800025a:   40cb        lsrs    r3, r1
 800025c:   4053        eors    r3, r2
 800025e:   617b        str r3, [r7, #20]
 8000260:   693b        ldr r3, [r7, #16]
 8000262:   3301        adds    r3, #1
 8000264:   613b        str r3, [r7, #16]
 8000266:   693b        ldr r3, [r7, #16]
 8000268:   f5b3 5f80   cmp.w   r3, #4096   ; 0x1000
 800026c:   dbda        blt.n   8000224 <test+0x14>
 800026e:   697b        ldr r3, [r7, #20]
 8000270:   4618        mov r0, r3
 8000272:   371c        adds    r7, #28
 8000274:   46bd        mov sp, r7
 8000276:   f85d 7b04   ldr.w   r7, [sp], #4
 800027a:   4770        bx  lr
```

It seems really weird to me as the code can be clearly enhanced in terms of speed. For instance, a single `uxtb` can be computed instead of two (if executed after the `eor`), so I believe there is something wrong going here. Why is the optimization flag not taken into account here? Is there something wrong with my makefile?

Comment: Build your code with `make CC='arm-none-eabi-gcc -v'`  and you'll see that the compiler is optimizing. Debug your `makefile` with [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/). Consider switching to some other build automationn tool, such as [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `make CC='arm-none-eabi-gcc -v'` results in the same way than `make` in my case

Comment: Then edit your `makefile` to have `CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc -v` and you'll see what your cross compiler is doing. You could even add `-ftime-report` to your `CFLAGS` there; that will show time spent by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) in optimizations.

Comment: please show an example C program that demonstrates this problem and the disassembly for the various optimization levels (that are exactly the same).

Comment: please show the actual commands shown on the terminal when run with this makefile for this .c file  arm-none-eabi-gcc ....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it seems that some time is spent for optimization but it does not the generated binary is the same at the end

Comment: @old_timer just added more material

Comment: @MikeKinghan just copied the output when I tried with -O1, but the output is exactly the same with -O3, I edited the post

Comment: 'env | grep CFLAGS'

Comment: Also some header may have a pragma to disable optimization.

Comment: @artlessnoise I confirm that no header has a pragma directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

uint32_t test(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    uint32_t tmp0, tmp1;
    uint32_t c;

    for(int i = 0; i< 4096; i++) {
        tmp0 = a & 0xff;
        tmp1 = b & 0xff;
        c = tmp0 ^ tmp1 ^ (a>>(i/512)) ^ (b >> (i/1024));
    }
    return c;
}

unsigned int hello ( void )
{
    return(test(0x75,0x14));
}
```

9.3.0 vs 9.2.1 is not going to be much different, I can specifically get a 9.2.1 if you want to see it but you can just do this yourself.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

-O0

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 so.c -c -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -o so.o

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <test>:
   0:   b480        push    {r7}
   2:   b087        sub sp, #28
   4:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
   6:   6078        str r0, [r7, #4]
   8:   6039        str r1, [r7, #0]
   a:   2300        movs    r3, #0
   c:   613b        str r3, [r7, #16]
   e:   e020        b.n 52 <test+0x52>
  10:   687b        ldr r3, [r7, #4]
  12:   b2db        uxtb    r3, r3
  14:   60fb        str r3, [r7, #12]
  16:   683b        ldr r3, [r7, #0]
  18:   b2db        uxtb    r3, r3
  1a:   60bb        str r3, [r7, #8]
  1c:   68fa        ldr r2, [r7, #12]
  1e:   68bb        ldr r3, [r7, #8]
  20:   405a        eors    r2, r3
  22:   693b        ldr r3, [r7, #16]
  24:   2b00        cmp r3, #0
  26:   da01        bge.n   2c <test+0x2c>
  28:   f203 13ff   addw    r3, r3, #511    ; 0x1ff
  2c:   125b        asrs    r3, r3, #9
  2e:   4619        mov r1, r3
  30:   687b        ldr r3, [r7, #4]
  32:   40cb        lsrs    r3, r1
  34:   405a        eors    r2, r3
  36:   693b        ldr r3, [r7, #16]
  38:   2b00        cmp r3, #0
  3a:   da01        bge.n   40 <test+0x40>
  3c:   f203 33ff   addw    r3, r3, #1023   ; 0x3ff
  40:   129b        asrs    r3, r3, #10
  42:   4619        mov r1, r3
  44:   683b        ldr r3, [r7, #0]
  46:   40cb        lsrs    r3, r1
  48:   4053        eors    r3, r2
  4a:   617b        str r3, [r7, #20]
  4c:   693b        ldr r3, [r7, #16]
  4e:   3301        adds    r3, #1
  50:   613b        str r3, [r7, #16]
  52:   693b        ldr r3, [r7, #16]
  54:   f5b3 5f80   cmp.w   r3, #4096   ; 0x1000
  58:   dbda        blt.n   10 <test+0x10>
  5a:   697b        ldr r3, [r7, #20]
  5c:   4618        mov r0, r3
  5e:   371c        adds    r7, #28
  60:   46bd        mov sp, r7
  62:   bc80        pop {r7}
  64:   4770        bx  lr

00000066 <hello>:
  66:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
  68:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
  6a:   2114        movs    r1, #20
  6c:   2075        movs    r0, #117    ; 0x75
  6e:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <test>
  72:   4603        mov r3, r0
  74:   4618        mov r0, r3
  76:   bd80        pop {r7, pc}
```

-O1

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O1 so.c -c -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <test>:
   0:   f44f 5380   mov.w   r3, #4096   ; 0x1000
   4:   3b01        subs    r3, #1
   6:   d1fd        bne.n   4 <test+0x4>
   8:   08ca        lsrs    r2, r1, #3
   a:   ea82 12d0   eor.w   r2, r2, r0, lsr #7
   e:   ea80 0301   eor.w   r3, r0, r1
  12:   b2db        uxtb    r3, r3
  14:   ea82 0003   eor.w   r0, r2, r3
  18:   4770        bx  lr

0000001a <hello>:
  1a:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
  1c:   2114        movs    r1, #20
  1e:   2075        movs    r0, #117    ; 0x75
  20:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <test>
  24:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
```

-O2

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <test>:
   0:   ea80 0301   eor.w   r3, r0, r1
   4:   08ca        lsrs    r2, r1, #3
   6:   ea82 10d0   eor.w   r0, r2, r0, lsr #7
   a:   b2db        uxtb    r3, r3
   c:   4058        eors    r0, r3
   e:   4770        bx  lr

00000010 <hello>:
  10:   2063        movs    r0, #99 ; 0x63
  12:   4770        bx  lr
```

-O3

```
00000000 <test>:
   0:   ea80 0301   eor.w   r3, r0, r1
   4:   08ca        lsrs    r2, r1, #3
   6:   ea82 10d0   eor.w   r0, r2, r0, lsr #7
   a:   b2db        uxtb    r3, r3
   c:   4058        eors    r0, r3
   e:   4770        bx  lr

00000010 <hello>:
  10:   2063        movs    r0, #99 ; 0x63
  12:   4770        bx  lr
```

-Os

```
00000000 <test>:
   0:   08cb        lsrs    r3, r1, #3
   2:   ea83 13d0   eor.w   r3, r3, r0, lsr #7
   6:   4048        eors    r0, r1
   8:   b2c0        uxtb    r0, r0
   a:   4058        eors    r0, r3
   c:   4770        bx  lr

0000000e <hello>:
   e:   2114        movs    r1, #20
  10:   2075        movs    r0, #117    ; 0x75
  12:   f7ff bffe   b.w 0 <test>
```

If all of these execute in the same amount of time then clearly yes you either have a build issue or there is an issue with your test.  If as you claim -O1 and -O2 and -O3 etc all produce the same output, then you are not actually using those optimization levels.

There is no reason to assume that -Os produces a smaller binary than -O2 or -O3.  Its just you are hinting at that desire.  You can create exceptions.

Also no reason to assume that compiled for size will execute faster nor will -O3, etc.  Especially on a platform like this (well all modern platforms) where some percentage of the performance is not related directly to the number or sequence of instructions, but the whole system.

You are on an stm32, cortex-m4 so you have the st flash cache thing which you cant turn off, now that is going to help all of the tests, but also going to hide things as well.  You have a clock init and then later a flash setup, wonder what is going on there if you are upping your clock then you have to slow the flash down first not after or you can crash.  For a test like this there generally is no reason to bump the clocks, you want to measure in timer clock cycles ideally system (as in cpu) clock cycles and then do things like mess with the flash wait states, at the slower clock speeds (some parts full range but) you can go with minimal flash wait states and then simply bump up the wait states for different tests without upping the clock to see how the flash affects it unfortunately this is an stm32.  To get around that you can run the test in sram.

Depending on the compile time options for the core, some cores have different fetch features and other features and you may have some core features you can mess with a simple alignment change of a tight loop like this can have a dramatic affect, same machine code starting at a different address, how it lines up in the fetch lines and cache lines can affect the benchmark results.

Note you can get the same results using the systick timer you need for the debugger timer.  Can wrap the gathering of time in the code under test (not in the function but when you lift the assembly language to make the code under test you can then add the time gathering just before and after, not incurring function call overhead which itself can vary from test to test.

If you are seeing the same machine code come out of the compiler for different settings then you are not actually building with those settings, not actually re-building the application, or some other form of user error (building here and using a binary from there).  As a result the same binary will give the same time plus or minus a clock ideally in a situation like this.  But that depends also on how you are running or re-running the test.  Do you want to see the cache effects or not, prime the cache then run the test, etc.

If when you start to see different machine code or if you really are seeing different machine code but getting the same time then the error is in the measurement of time which is an often overlooked issue with benchmarking.  your method seems fine so long as you are really seeing that timer, and have done tests to see that the timer is counting and in the direction you expect it to go.  If this is a number of instructions counter not execution of time, then you can still test it to see it is doing what you think.  I have no use for those debug tools so don't dabble in them nor know them as intimately as I know other things about these systems.

Being an m4 there might be other features you can turn on/off to see performance differences based on code generated, branch prediction, caching, mmu-like-thing, etc.

It may be the order of the flags you are using (the reason for each of those flags being a first question) relative to the -O3, some may be negating other optimization features.

Curious to know what the real goal is here. Understand that benchmarks are nonsense, because they are so easy to manipulate, the same high level code is not expected to produce the same results in the same target with the same or different tools for various reasons.  dumb down the command line and try clang/llvm vs gnu or try gcc 4.x.x, 5.x.x, etc on up.  after 4.x.x the output started to get bloated, the compiler wasn't doing as good of a job, for something like this though they should be pretty close but at the same time one fewer or more instruction, a simple alignment difference could make two tests vastly different in terms of results.

Then when you put back clock setups that changes how things work, so you may be able to let's say use no wait states (flash probably runs at have the CPU rate, so there is a wait built in) up to 25mhz as an example then add a wait state up to say 50 and so on.  Varies by design some newer parts the flash can run much faster than older parts, but at 25mhz vs 8, the same number of clocks is an overall smaller number of time, wall clock time.  At the boundary you can arguably not bump the wait states if you create/modify the clock init code and get that performance boost, but just over that boundary you get a performance hit with the flash wait state increase. So there is a performance balance there.

### Summary

If the same code is coming out of the compiler then it is your command line, you can easily simplify the command line to see that the tools will produce different code.  If your comparison is wrong and the code is different then the problem is how you are timing the code which is often where benchmarks go wrong, that and other factors not related to the compiler command line.  Benchmarks are in general nonsense because they can be manipulated to show different results (even without changing the high level source code of the test).

Try simplifying the command line, examine each option you have there and justify why it is there for your specific application.  Validate the timer the best you can or instruction counter whichever this is (and understand that counting instructions executed is not directly related to performance, you can have 100x instructions that execute faster than some other solution).

No reason to expect -Os to produce smaller code, one would hope but there are exceptions.  Likewise -Os might execute faster than -O2 or -O3, no reason to expect the larger number optimization level to produce "faster" code.

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling the code with -O0 flag.

It is clearly seen here: 
https://godbolt.org/z/qZPYqJ

So the compiler is always right. No missed optimisations found.

Answer (score 0):

Well the real answer is not really easy, but before disasembling something one should know what optimization actually is and how compilers achieves their goals.
Considering gcc there is barely no differences between Os and 03 since they turn on almost the same internal flags except loop unroling for Os.

In addition with nowaday cpu having everything in cache is anyway faster.